# AES decrypted output to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am playing a CTF challenge . I have been given encrypted file and Code used for encryption where I've to find the time used for seed variable for decryption . But I'm unable to decrypt the output from bytes to string .
Here is the code used in the CTF challenge -

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from datetime import datetime
import hashlib
from time import strftime

seed = str(datetime.now())
key = hashlib.sha256(seed.encode('utf-8')).digest()

IV = 16 * '\x00'

mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(key, mode, IV=IV)

text = open('flag.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
text = text + "0" * (16-len(text)%16)
ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)
target = open('flag.enc.txt', 'wb')

target.write(ciphertext)
target.close()
```

And here is the code I've used for decryption -

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from datetime import datetime
import hashlib
import base64
from time import strftime

seedOrg = '2021-07-06 03:16:51.'
IV = 16 * '\x00'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
with open('/home/teja_mxx/Desktop/CapStone/encDec/flag.enc.txt', 'rb') as f:
    encText = f.read()
print(encText)

for x in range(1):
    if len(str(x)) < 9:
        llen = len(str(x))
        milli = ("0" * (9 - llen))+str(x)
        seed = seedOrg+milli
        key = hashlib.sha256(seed.encode('utf-8')).digest()
        decryptor = AES.new(key, mode, IV=IV)
        decryptedText = decryptor.decrypt(encText)
        print(decryptedText.decode())
```

And I'm getting this error . How do I resolve it ?
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Comment: The byte-nonsense returned by a decryption with wrong key has usually no valid UTF-8-encoding.

Comment: Have you tried to encrypt with known seed and then decrypt with your code using this particular seed to test if your decryption basically works as expected?

Comment: Yea @MichaelButscher .  I did try encryption decryption with known seed . It still shows the same error

Comment: Right, so a binary compare of the seeds succeeded?